# 100% "google.play.games.games.v1.Applications.RecordApplicationActivity" since one month

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-play-games

I have a problem with my Google Play Cloud api. I tried to find some sort of support and was lead to Stack Overflow. I am using the "google play game service" for my Unity-based game (to store the save-game via Cloud).

Since my newest releases I had a small issue with the GPGS-implementation, which I fixed immediately. Every error disappeared after my fix. But since the patch last month, one error still remains with 100% appearance:

"google.play.games.games.v1.Applications.RecordApplicationActivity"

I can't find anything online about similar issues or nearly the source of this call, to fix this on my own.

I can't reach that bug via testings on my test-devices, nor does it seem to affect my users dramatically, but an error is nothing I should ignore...

What things can I do to investigate this?

[This is the most detailed Error-Help I can get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXA1W.png)

Answer (score 1):

Always check your SHA1 key!

I assumed the guide next to the SHA1-Input to get the SHA1-Key was the right one for me. Apparently there are 2 SHA1 Keys (one "SHA1-App-Key" and one "SHA1-Upload-Key")... And you don't even need that "cmd-guide" from google. If you already uploaded your app, you can find BOTH keys in the google console. Under "Release" & "App-Integration".